# Is there a way to get the BarCode format name when using Firebase MLkit Library?

Tags: android, firebase, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

I am using FireBase MLkit to scan barcode for my Android App. The FirebaseVisionBarcode is returning the barcode type (i.e. its encoding) in Integer format. But is there any way, where i can get the barcode type name. I found an internal method(FirebaseVisionBarcode.zzox(). This method has been remove in the latest version) is returning the name of the barcode Type. But i cant use the internal function. Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about the barcode format meaning for the integers?

Here is the list of all the supported formats:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/barcode/FirebaseVisionBarcode#FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS

Comment: No. I know the supported formats. After the Scan has completed, I want to know whether we can GET the Format from the Result

Comment: How about this API? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/barcode/FirebaseVisionBarcode#getFormat()

Comment: No. This returns integer. I can write some logic to show what format of barcode based on the value returned from getFormat(). But I just want to know if there is any way to get the format as a string, so that I can display it directly. Perhaps there is no API as of now for this.

Comment: Right, there is no direct API to return the name as string, but it should be achieved by your own mapping easily, say from the integers to the strings.